# Android WebView incorect size (js window.screen)

Tags: android, webview

In WebView on mobile js code give:

```
alert(window.screen.width); -> 720px
alert(window.devicePixelRatio); -> 2
```

In Browser on mobile js code give:

```
alert(window.screen.width); -> 360px
alert(window.devicePixelRatio); -> 2
```

How can I make the behavior (`windows.screen` varibale) of the WebView android component same as Browser?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect

**Desktop Sites**
In some cases, you may need to display content that isn’t designed for mobile devices – for example, if you’re displaying content you don’t control. In this case, you need to force the WebView to use a desktop-size viewport:

```
setUseWideViewPort(true)
setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
```